# Permissions on /opt

Tags: linux, debian, file-permissions

I have a SSD and a HDD in my laptop. I have configured my Debian so that / is on my SSD and /home is on my HDD. To make sure my own downloaded programs (eclipse and such) use the speed of my SSD I thought I would put them in /opt en make symbolic links to /usr/bin. I tried this with eclipse and it worked but when I try to read or write anything I get permission errors (since everything in /opt is owned by root). Should I chown everything to my local user or is there a better way of doing this?